# Find the sum of the infinite series [1+(5/1!)+(8/2!)+(11/3!)+.....]

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

Excluding the 1st term of the series **1**, if we start from the **2nd term-($\frac{5}{1!}$)**, I can locate that the **numerators** are in **A.P** with common difference **3**, & **1st term 5**.

Whereas the denominators are of the form **n! where $n \in [1,\infty)$**.So, the **n th term** is $[\frac{5+(n-1)3}{n!}]$.

But this is given as an infinite series & I am unable to solve this factorial-A.P combination.

Please Help

**Thank You**

Comment: Do you know the sum of the infinite series $1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + \cdots$?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{2n+3}{n!}=\frac2{(n-1)!}+\frac3{n!}$

Comment: I would prefer $3+2n$. (The first term doesn't fit, we can take care of that later.) Note that $\frac{3+2n}{n!}=\frac{3}{n!}+\frac{2}{(n-1)!}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1 + 5/1! + 8/2! + \ldots = -1 + \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} \frac{5 + (3n -3)}{n!} = -1 + 5 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = 5e - 1$$

Comment: Where did the $(3n-3)$ term disappear?

Comment: @Wojowu: I didn't want to write out a complete solution. If you look at it closely, you'll see where it disappeared.

Comment: @BolzWeir: Can you please explain that why have you taken -1?& the series is rearranged as {-1+[(2/0!)+(5/1!)+(8/3!)+...]}, then the 1st term would have been 2,i.e numerator [2+(n-1)3].

Comment: @InfinitelyUndefined: because if we would write the series as it is, it would be: $1 + \sum_{\text{**n=1**}}^{\infty} \frac{5 + 3(n-1)}{n!}$. To make the sum from $n=0$, we'll have to subtract $2$, because the evaluation of the sequence at $n = 0$ is $2$.

Comment: @InfinitelyUndefined: now I understand what you're talking about. Yes, I can re-arrange the series as such, and as a result, the sequence being summed would be what you've described **but** for $n \ge 1$. It is equivalently what I have written, but for $ n \ge 0$.

Comment: @BolzWeir: Yes,i was also thinking that.Now i've got it.Thanks.